# Lua - Using string.find to return true if between 2 special characters

Tags: design-patterns, lua, lua-patterns

I need a pattern that will work with string.find (or string.match if necessary) that will return true if a "table path" string matches. This is my function:

```
local function FindValueFromPattern(myTable, pattern, previousPath)
    for key, value in pairs(myTable) do
        local path;

        if (not previousPath) then
            path = key;
        else
            path = string.format("%s.%s", previousPath, key);
        end

        if (path:find(pattern)) then
            return value;

        elseif (type(value) == "table") then
            value = FindValueFromPattern(value, pattern, path);

            if (value ~= nil) then
               return value;
            end
        end
    end

    return nil;
end

local tbl = {}
tbl.settings = {};
tbl.settings.module = {};
tbl.settings.module.appearance = {};
tbl.settings.module.appearance.color = "blue";

print(FindValueFromPattern(tbl, "settings.module.appearance.color")); -- prints "blue";
```

The code above works BUT I want to now change the pattern to:

`"module.<ANY>.color"` where `<ANY>` is any child table of "module" and also has a child table called "color", so when traversing down the table, a value will be returned regardless of what table is used (does not have to be the appearance table):

```
-- should also print "blue" ("setting." should not be required);
print(FindValueFromPattern(tbl, "module.<ANY>.color"));
```

Rather than returning found values straight away, I may have to change the logic to insert found values in a table and then return the table after the for-loop but I wrote this quickly to illustrate the problem.

So the question is, what would that pattern look like? Thank you.

Comment: Are numeric keys allowed?  Should `"settings.module[3].color"` be found?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Good question. No, because the path is artificially created and I join each key explicitly with `"."` so if the pairs function returned a number then, for example, it would still look like `"module.2.property"` and I can use this in the pattern I send to the function. Thanks for asking.

Comment: To match the `"module.<ANY>.color"` string you might use a `"module%.[^.]+%.color"` pattern. If you need to extract the ANY part, wrap the `[^.]+` with capturing group: `"module%.([^.]+)%.color"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that looks like a great answer. Not necessary for the solution I posted but would using `"module%.([^.]+)%.([^.]+)%color"` also work for cases where there are more than 1 of these keys? I might need to do something like this in the future.

Comment: The point is that `[^.]+` matches *any* consecutive chars other than `.` one or more times. I guess yes. If you need to restrict the chars to letters and digits use `%w+` instead. If you need to match any 0+ chars use `.-` (to get to the first `.color`) or `.+` (to match up to the last `.color`).

Comment: Should `settings.module.appearance.appearance.color` be found?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff No, not if you're only using `"module%.[^.]+%.color"` like Wiktor previously pointed out (with the intent to only match 1 key inbetween module and color). Not tested this with `settings.module.appearance.appearance.color`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `"If you need to match any 0+ chars use .- (to get to the first .color) or .+ (to match up to the last .color)."`, I was trying to get that to work but wasn't sure how. I'll do some reading and experimenting to try and get that to work, thanks.

Comment: Why not sure how? E.g, `"module%.(.-)%.color"`,  `"module%.(.+)%.color"`, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I thought you meant something like `[^.]+%.` vs `[^.]-%.`. I see.

Answer (score 0):

What you do there is extremely inefficient. A much better approach would be to split the string at each `.` and just index the table.

A simple version that doesn't accept "any" could look like this

```
function findintable(tab, path)
    local pos = path:find(".", 1, true)
    if pos then
        local tab = tab[path:sub(1, pos-1)]
        if not type(tab) then error("Expected value to be table, got "..type(tab), 1) end
        return findintable(tab, path:sub(pos+1, -1))
    else
        return tab[path]
    end
end
```

Adding the possibility for an *any key* (he... he... he...) would add some complexity and needs a loop, but it's also doable

```
    function findintable(tab, path)
        local pos = path:find(".", 1, true)
        if not pos then
            return tab[path]
        end
        local key, rest = path:sub(1, pos-1), path:sub(pos+1, -1)
        if key == "*" then
            for k, v in pairs(tab) do
                if type(v)~="table" then return end
                local res = findintable(v, rest)
                if res then return res end
            end
            return
        else
            local tab = tab[path:sub(1, pos-1)]
            if not type(tab) then error("Expected value to be table, got "..type(tab), 1) end
            return findintable(tab, path:sub(pos+1, -1))
        end
    end
```

This should do what you want. Just change the "*" to whatever you want the placeholder to be.

Answer (score 0):

I used `gmatch` with the pattern `%.*([^.]+)` to iterate through each `key` in the keys provided.

This function could be changed to output a table of all `color`s found, but currently only returns a single value. The value returned is the `color` found or `nil` if no matches were found.

```
function FindValueFromPattern(tab, keys)
    local t_ref = tab

    for k in keys:gmatch("%.*([^.]+)") do
        if k == "<ANY>" and type(t_ref) == "table" then
            local temp1
            local temp2

            for any in pairs(t_ref) do
                local new_keys = keys:gsub(k, any)
                temp1 = FindValueFromPattern(tab, new_keys)

                new_keys = keys:gsub(k, any .. ".<ANY>")
                temp2 = FindValueFromPattern(tab, new_keys)

                if temp1 or temp2 then
                    break
                end
            end
            t_ref = temp1 or temp2
            break
        else
            if t_ref == nil or type(t_ref) ~= "table" then
                t_ref = nil
                break
            end

            t_ref = t_ref[k]
        end
    end
    return t_ref
end
```

Example use:

```
sample = {
    a = {
        b = {
            c = {
                color = "blue",

            },
            roloc = 1,
            color = "red",
        },
        d = {
            e = {
                color = "purple",

            },
            roloc = "wolley",
            color = "yellow",
        },
    }
}
colorFound = FindValueFromPattern(sample, "a.<ANY>.color")
if colorFound then
    print("Found: " .. colorFound )
else
    print("No matches found")
end
>> Found: red
```

Keep in mind the behavior is nondeterministic, it is possible for the output to be `yellow` rather then `red`, and it cannot be known which it will be until the code is run.